# Django admin templates looks different between server and local

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

When I deployed my app on heroku, it looked different from what I have on local server. It just displayed basic html, no css at all.

I was trying to add local admin templates to my new template folder. But still didn't work.

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

How can I make it work. What other information should I provide? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because static files like css are not served directly in production mode (when DEBUG=False). you have to run following command in your production environment.

`python manage.py collectstatic`

For more information about running this command in heroku, please follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) article.